# Company mail configuration in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, email

I need to configure my company email to iPad. Following is screen shot of the manual for mail configuration which company mailed to me. I tried giving incoming mail server as specified but it didn't work . Where will i add port no? i didn't come across it while configuring. Whenever i try they send me an error "would you like to configure with out using SSL?" Any method for knowing incoming and outgoing server?

Screen shot :

[image]

7.Give Incoming server as 10.0.4.24 and Port as 50110 

8.Give Login ID(if different from e-mil address)as SR NO 

9.Give Outgoing server as 10.0.4.24 and Port as 25 
Click Next

Answer (score 1):

The configuration totally depends on the email server details. If your admin has emailed you these settings trust that they will be complete. The settings you have in the screenshot above would be meant for an office computer residing inside the company office.

The problem why you cannot connect to the email server would be because the IP addresses are internal (10.0.0.x). This means that you need to be connected to the company network to access the email server with these details. This leaves you with a few different solutions:

1. On an iPad this would mean that you would need to be connected to the company wifi whilst attempting to fetch your email. You would need to sit inside your office and connect.
2. Ask your admin for VPN access, and through your iPad iOS settings enable the VPN access. This creates a virtual tunnel over the internet wherever you are directly to the company internal network, making the iPad believe that it is accessing the company network directly. You can then use the email settings as per your screenshot to connect.
3. Ask your admin for the public IP addresses to the email server and use them for your email seetings instead. (example: 212.120.243.xxx)

Hope you find the solution you need. Good luck!